# How to go one level up with batch from CWD

Tags: batch-file

How to go one level up with %~dp0? 
I have already tried %~dp0.. and "%~dp0..". 
Both not working! Please help! it is just printing .. with the current path and not evaluating it.

The log in which my info which i want to pull is one level up. I use that in the for-loop to fetch it. Like this:

```
for /f "tokens=8" %%i in (perf.txt) do (
set read=%%i
goto displayread
)
```

But I want to get it from a path like this:

```
for /f "tokens=8" %%i in (C:\perf.txt) do (
set read=%%i
goto displayread
)
```

It is not allowing to me to put a path. So i used  %~dp0perf.txt. But problem is the calling batch is in level up and is creating the text there.

Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Did you try `cd ..` or `cd %~dp0..`?

Comment: I cant change directory because my calling script would then lose control if i do cd..

Comment: If you don't want to change the current directory, what do you mean with `How to go one level up`? Perhaps you should show your relevant code

Comment: @jeb I have changed the question. Perhaps now it would make more sense? Also how to specify a path to a text file inside for loop?

Comment: can you use `pushd` (and `popd` before exiting)?

Comment: You could try `FOR /F ... ( %~dp0..\perf.txt ) do (`